# When two Jabber (XMPP) clients connected, only one is able to receive messages, both can send

Tags: xmpp

I have a Windows XMPP client - PSI and an android one - IMO. I'm connected to the same custom server, using two different resources (hostname on desktop, don't know what IMO uses as resource). When someone sends me a message, only desktop client is able to receive it. Android client can only send.

What to configure in clients to be able to receive messages on both clients simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. XMPP protocol has priorities assigned to resources. See 11.1 in http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#rules. Valid range is -127 .. +128

IMO sends priority 1 (at least in my version). Setting priority in PSI to -120 made my phone client always receive the message. I'll play with priorities to take advantage of auto-away feature that lowers priority.

Comment: I guess some servers are configured so that they send messages to *all* clients with same priority.

Comment: @unor might as well be that way. What's also nice is once receive a message with my Android client and reply with desktop one, susequent messages go to the desktop client.

Comment: is there any way we can achieve it using ejabberd?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got admin permissions on an Openfire server, setting the system property "route.all-resources" to "true" should allow all connected client to receive a message sent to a Jabber ID. This worked in my case.